# Opening another view from a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am attempting to open links embedded in a custom table view cell using a UIWebView in the same scene. However, I when I tap the button the webview doesn't open in response. The button is working (it will print an NSLog), and the webview will show if I set it visible in ViewDidLoad in the "HouseItemsViewController."

The Table View contains my custom cells, and I am trying to show the highlighted View:

[Imgur image of my "House Items View Controller" Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I60uu.png)

The HouseItemsViewController contains a method to accept a NSURL:

```
- (void)displayWebViewWithURL:(NSURL *)targetURL
{
    NSURL *url = targetURL;
    NSURLRequest *myrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:myrequest];
    theURLView.hidden=NO;
}
```

The custom table view cell includes an action:

```
- (IBAction)congressUrlLink:(id)sender
{
    HouseItemsViewController* billViewController = (HouseItemsViewController*)self.tapHandler;
    [billViewController displayWebViewWithURL:congressUrl];
}
```

Where tapHandler is defined:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^tapHandler)(id sender);
```

What's the right way to reference the HouseItemsViewController from here and to execute the displayWebViewWithURL:(NSURL *)targetURL method?[

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the tapHandler manually as a delegate.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) HouseItemsViewController *delegate;
```

synthesize it, and assign it manually after initializing your table view cell:

```
 [myCell setDelegate:self];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, KDaker. You would set that delegate property and synthesize it in the cell's header file or in the table view's header? And would you then be calling "[myCell setDelegate:self]; in the tableview controller where the cell's created?

And would you change any of the code I shared above?  Thanks for the help. Every time I think I started to get this stuff I realize I know nothing.

Comment: I added the "selfDelegate" line where the cells are created in the TableViewController, but it returns the error: Incompatible pointer types sending "TableViewController" to parameter of type "HouseItemsViewController *"
The HouseItemsViewController is what contains the view with the webview I'm trying to unhide.

Comment: @TedCap you need to synthesize it (cells implementation file). Now the `setDelegate` is called where the cell is created, usually in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I pass `self` as the delegate because i assumed `HouseItemsViewController` is what contains your tableview, isnt that the case? in your cell's header file, don't `import` the `HouseItems...` class, instead use this: `@class HouseItemsViewController`

Comment: No luck. Still unresponsive.
The TableView is an IBOutlet in a "BillTableViewController" @interface BillTableViewController : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>. This BillTableViewController is within the view hierarchy controlled by the HouseItemsViewController as per the image linked in the original post. Is there another way I should be going about this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, you know what I think is messing it up is that the button the URL is attached to exists on a xib independent of the storyboard.